# A good UI design for rating in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

im trying to add a "rating" system to an existing form (i.e 1 star, 2 Star or poor, average,good,excellent etc).
Does anyone know of a way to achieve this that is aesthetically pleasing with good UX either in .Net or a free 3rd party control?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, SilverLight or Asp.Net?

Comment: Sorry, should have stated - I'm using WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Check the ASP.NET Ajax control:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Rating/Rating.aspx

Comment: Sorry, as above - I should have mentioned im using WinForms. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Starbox.
It's commercial, but the best one I've ever seen.
http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/starbox/

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are ratng? Depending on that you may want to be a bit different. For example, The ASP.NET Templates include a site called The Beerhouse, wich uses a glass rating, showuing different number of beer glasses or half full glasses.

Another product I worked on sold Chocolate, so the rating was what looked like a chocolate bar, with different amounts of chocolate being 'eaten' off the end..